# Different metric of file size as output of ls command

Tags: command-line, ls

Why is `ls` command yielding different metric of file size? Example:

```
haniya@r079008:~/data$ ls -l
total 3948604
-rwxrwxrwx 1 haniya haniya   21254426 Mei 24 19:34 cliente_tabla.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haniya haniya    6167128 Jul  2 02:03 cliente_tabla.csv.zip
```

If I assume the size is displayed in Byte, why `total` is given in KB.

While

```
haniya@r079008:~/data$ ls -s cliente_tabla.csv
20760 cliente_tabla.csv
```

Now the size is in KB. That makes the information unclear (inconsistent). Is there any way to 'regularize' the metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`total` and `ls -s` by default print the number of blocks of 1024 bytes or the size defined in `BLOCKSIZE` or `BLOCK_SIZE` environment variables.

To "regularize" the units for `ls -l` output add `--block-size` argument, for example:

- for KiB (2^10):

  ```
  ls -l --block-size=K
  ```
- for MB (10^6):

  ```
  ls -l --block-size=MB
  ```
- You can also specify `1M` to display only numbers and skip the unit.

For all units and options refer to the [Block Size](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Block-size.html) chapter of GNU docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -lh
```

Will list file sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)

```
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm       68K Aug 19 19:30 syslog
```